# Is there a way to insert text from a different cell into a function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So far, cell H24 creates a string value providing the place I need to read from in a separate google sheet. Now that I know where I have to read in that sheet I want to put that into the IMPORTRANGE function to get its value.

H24 in the cell is a function, but it looks like "Fall 2022!E65" after I used concatenate CHAR(34) to add the " to the string Fall 2022!E65. I then tried simply placing H24 into the IMPORTRANGE, but to no avail. I also tried using the INDIRECT function, but I receive an error for that as well.

Works: H25=IF(IMPORTRANGE("googlesheeturl.com", "Fall 2022!E65")="Yes",1,0)

Does not work:

H24="Fall 2022!E65"

H25=IF(IMPORTRANGE("googlesheeturl.com", H24)="Yes",1,0)

Does not work:

H22=65

H25=IF(IMPORTRANGE("googlesheetsurl.com", INDIRECT("'Fall 2022!E" & H22 & "'"))="Yes",1,0)

ERROR: Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is ''Fall 2022!E65''. It is not a valid cell/range reference.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `Fall 2022!E65` in H24 **without quotes**

and put this formula wherever you like:

```
=if(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_link", H24)="Yes", 1,0)
```

Using cell reference in the formula will convert the value directly to a string. Therefore, you are not required to put in extra quotes.